# Fading blocks animation fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a slider with fading blocks animation, just like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4nsJE/). Trouble is that in my case I'm trying to do it fullscreen, meaning that height and width will be variable. This means that the background-position trick won't work, as it won't resize the background to fit the screen but rather take it 'as is'. It's easier to see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/43s4x1s5/) (keep in mind that *#slides* would be height 100% and width 100% aswell as *.slide>img*). I've ran out of ideas to fix it, any help would be appreciated. I'd prefer not using jQuery, but if it is necessary, it'll be okay.

Thank you beforehand.

My script so far is:

```
function animateBlocks(x,y,speed) {
var width = document.getElementById('slides').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('slides').offsetHeight;
var newWidth = width/x;
var newHeight = height/y;

for (var i = 0; i<(x*y); i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.className = "slide-block";
    newDiv.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
    newDiv.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    newDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].firstElementChild.src + '")';
    newDiv.style.backgroundPosition = ('-' + newDiv.offsetLeft + 'px ' + '-' + newDiv.offsetTop + 'px');

    if (i == x*y-1) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].firstElementChild.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Like this ?http://jsfiddle.net/43s4x1s5/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it was what I was looking for. However, I've seen you've used `window.innerWidth` to get browser's with, but in the tests I tried (in Firefox) it included the scrollbar, which would break the code. Is that normal behaviour? Also, does declaring variables before the while and for statement improve perfomance?

Comment: It's because firefox's window's width on jsfiddle seems to be some floating points, and we all know that when dealing with float, it's should be treat carefully, like my case it's `644.8`, and `window.innerWidth` gives me `645`, it 100% certain that the blocks will be wider and break. I've change the way to get the real width by `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();` and round down to make later divides never have change to be greater. And 2nd, it's just because `var` is function scope, and I don't like to redeclare it in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the feedback of the comments, the issue may happen when there's float on `window`'s `width`. So use `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();` to get a precise size, and round down, which may sacrifice some pixels, to ensure that blocks won't overflow to next row. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43s4x1s5/4/)

```js
function animateBlocks(x,y,speed) {
    var img = document.querySelector('#slides img');
    var viewPortSize = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Round down if there's floating points on width.
    var windowWidth = Math.floor(viewPortSize.width);
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
 var newWidth = windowWidth / x;
 var newHeight = windowHeight / y;
    
    var newDiv;
    var domFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i +=1) {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j += 1) {
            newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            domFrag.appendChild(newDiv);
            newDiv.className = "slide-block";
            newDiv.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
            newDiv.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            newDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].firstElementChild.src + '")';
            newDiv.style.backgroundSize = windowWidth + 'px ' + windowHeight + 'px';

            newDiv.style.backgroundPosition = ('-' + newWidth*j + 'px ' + '-' + newHeight*i + 'px');
        }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i<(x*y); i++) {

 }
    document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].appendChild(domFrag);
    document.getElementsByClassName('active-slide')[0].firstElementChild.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;  /* makes the scroll bar disappear. */
} 

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
 }
 
 .slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
 }
 
 .slide>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
 }
 
 .active-slide {
  display: block;
 }

.slide-block {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="animateBlocks(5,5,0)">Click here to see how it looks</button>
<ul id="slides">
 <li class="slide active-slide">
  <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg">
 </li>
</ul>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p>How it should look</p>
    <img style="height: 100px;" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg">
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can get the width of any width: '100%' element. Thank you!